# Google Charts Pyramid population number format

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How can i make a population pyramid with thousands separators?
The problem is that I have to put this format:

```
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            pattern: ';'
        });
```

Because I don't want that negative symbol appear.

Answer (score 1):

I add an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnenjgkg/9/

```
  var dataArray = [`enter code here`
    ['Age', 'Male', 'Female'],
    ['0-4 years',   106, -104],
    ['5-9 years',   91,  -86 ],
    ['10-14 years', 79,  -77 ],
    ['15-19 years', 6008,  -6004 ],
    ['20-24 years', 62,  -58 ],
    ['25-29 years', 56,  -53 ],
    ['30-34 years', 51,  -46 ],
    ['35-39 years', 48,  -41 ],
    ['40-44 years', 43,  -35 ],
    ['45-49 years', 39,  -30 ],
    ['50-54 years', 33,  -27 ],
    ['55-59 years', 32,  -25 ],
    ['60-64 years', 27,  -20 ],
    ['64-69 years', 19,  -16 ],
    ['70-74 years', 13,  -12 ],
    ['75-79 years', 8,   -7  ],
    ['80-84 years', 3,   -3  ],
    ['85-89 years', 1,   -1  ],
    ['90-94 years', 0,   0   ],
    ['95+ years',   0,   0   ]
  ];

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: ';'
  });

  formatter.format(data, 1)
  formatter.format(data, 2)

  -----

  if i change this for this:
```

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '###,###'
  });
      show with commas but appear '-' on females

Comment: Thank you for your example, putting  `formatter.format(data, 1)
  formatter.format(data, 2) `, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Some expert on Google Chart? :)

In the documentation not appear:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat

I only need put the number in absolute value...